# why the ping value different from the mtr?

Tags: networking, ping, mtr

Why the ping command's output value is different from the mtr command ? I am curious。

ping: about 0.5ms

mtr: about  2.3ms

[image]

Comment: because mtr != icmp?  MTR sends out a udp packet with a specific TTL.

Comment: No, MTR sends out ICMP packages by default.

Answer (score 3):

Because mtr != ping?

Depending on your switches mtr sends out an UDP packet with a specific TTL, and gets a ICMP reply?

Ping sends out an ICMP echo request?  Also different size by default.  At least on my an IPv4 ping is 64 bytes, the UDP packet mtr sends is 48 bytes.  The replies from the router need to be an ICMP time exceeded instead of a ICMP echo reply.

Anyway the tools work differently, and so you might get different results.

Comment: So actually.. MTR sends out ICMP echo packages by default with an incrementing TTL (Time-To-Live) per packet. If you wish to test TCP or UDP packages instead you should use the `--udp` or `--tcp` flag (or press "u" via the interactive menu). With a default package size of 64 bytes and an interval of 1 second.